# File or directory not found after first loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, while-loop

I am trying to create a python program that "overwrites" a list (that I create earlier in the program) after a certain number of words are entered. I say "overwrite" because once I reach my max word count, I get my program to delete the file and rerun the program and recreate the file. The program runs fine at first but when the first loop comes I get a file or directory 'History.txt' not found. Not sure why even though I create the file itself in the program

```
# This creates the file and everything below the first line is formatting to it looks nice
    with open("History.txt", "a") as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'", "")
            if k.find("space") > 0:
                f.write('\n')
            elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                f.write(k)
```

```
# This defined the number of words in the list
    filename = 'History.txt'
    numWords = 0

    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            wordsList = line.split()
            numWords += len(wordsList)
```

EDIT:
Here is some reproducible code. It is a bit long for minimal code, but the on_press and write_file can be ignored as they are just for word formatting for the .txt file. You will notice that this all works fine and the History.txt file gets deleted. But introducing the while loop causes the error.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

while True:
    count = 0
    keys = []


    def on_press(key):
        global keys, count

        keys.append(key)
        count += 1

        if count >= 1:  # Starts recording keys after I press any key
            count = 0
            write_file(keys)
            keys = []


    def write_file(keys):  # This function creates spaces between words
        with open("History.txt", "a") as f:
            for key in keys:
                k = str(key).replace("'", "")
                if k.find("space") > 0:
                    f.write('\n')
                elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                    f.write(k)


    def on_release(key):
        filename = 'History.txt'
        num_words = 0

        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                words_list = line.split()
                num_words += len(words_list)

        if num_words == 5:
            import os  # I changed this from the earlier remove function but it does the same
            os.remove(filename)

            return False


    with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Comment: @simonN `'a'` will create the file if not exists, else append to it ...

Comment: Check your programs logic - do you realy append after deleting or do you delete, read append

Comment: I do remove it. Near my last line I use an os.remove('History.txt') function. The file does get removed as I tested it without a while loop and it does delete it. But when I run the loop and try to append it again, I get an error that it does not exist and I am confused because the append function does not require existence.

Comment: Your error does not stem from the code opening with "a" - your flow must "r" the no longer existing file. Please post a [mre] that we can run and advice you that replicates your error